# Declare multiple variables for use in macros in SAS?

Tags: sas

I reuse the same constant variables multiple times in my program so I wanted to declare them all in a macro and then call that macro for my functions.

I have an example like this that works

```
%macro vars();
    %let trans_1 = ever_30_ct;
    %let trans_2 = ever_60_ct;
%mend vars;

%macro run_();
    %vars();
    proc sql;
    select &trans_1 from va_purchase_fico_cts;
    run;
%mend run_;

%run_();
```

However if I change the run_ macro to this it doesn't work anymore.

```
%macro run_();
    %vars();
    proc sql;
    select &trans_1 , &trans_2 from va_purchase_fico_cts;
    run;
%mend run_;
```

It says &trans_2 can not be resolved. Does anyone understand why I can't do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macro variable scope. It shouldn't work either time. Most likely you've declared the variable trans_1 in your testing at some point.

Basically, the macro is creating local macro variables that no longer exist once the macro is finished. Declare them as global macro variables and you'll be able to use them outside the macro.

```
%macro vars();
    %global trans_1;
    %global trans_2;
    %let trans_1 = ever_30_ct;
    %let trans_2 = ever_60_ct;
%mend vars;
```

Answer (score 1):

A `%global` is the simplest solution.

Because I work on several projects concurrently, I try to avoid global variables. I prefer to write an entry point macro for each project I am working on. Then I call other macros from there. This allows you to declare as many `%local` variables as needed in that entry point. Those variables will disappear when the task is complete. like:

```
%macro wrap_foo/des='Entry point for task foo';
    %local _trans1 _trans2;
    %foo;
%mend;
```

If you have a need to initialize the variables in a parametric way, then you can create a macro that uses the *name* of the variable. I often use this to create custom log messages:

```
%macro init_constants( varname1, varname2, project )
/des='Parameterized constant initializer.';
    %let &varname1 = &project.1;
    %let &varname2 = &project.2;
%mend;

%macro foo/des='Actual task foo';
    %init_constants( _trans1, _trans2, bar );
    %put &=_trans1 &=_trans2;
%mend;

%wrap_foo;
```